# What is the correct permission to get user's preferred time zone?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I try to get user's preferred time zone using Microsoft Graph API.

Based on [the document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings), I need permission **MailboxSettings.Read**. I have that permission. I tried

```
GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings/timeZone
```

If the `id|userPrincipalName` is myself, I can get the time zone successfully.

However, if it is other's, I got error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0ef0b04c-af0c-445f-87b8-a7d93e3809ff",
            "date": "2018-03-10T07:56:26"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct permission to get other users' preferred time zone? Thanks

Comment: That should be all you need but if you're using delegated permissions, I believe you can only retrieve the current user's mailbox settings.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thanks, if the app can know users' preferred time zone, it can better serve them. Isn't the reason we create preferred time zone API? I believe `GET /me/mailboxSettings` is for getting your own, and we create `GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings` is for getting other. So there must be some way to use this API, right? Then what is the correct permission?

Comment: You have the correct permissions but you can only use `/users/{id}` when using Application Scopes (`client_credentials`). Generally, apps don't take into account the recipients timezone. And for meetings, FindMeetingTimes is already taking it into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Marc LaFleur's help.

I just notice the small difference in the [permission doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference).

> 1) Delegated permissions
>
> MailboxSettings.Read - Read user mailbox settings
>
> 2) Application permissions
>
> MailboxSettings.Read - Read **all** user mailbox settings

Now it makes sense!